# Starting rpcgssd on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, nfs, kerberos

I'm running CentOS 7.0.1406, and have problems with NFSv4, authenticating using krb5p. Neither idmapd nor gssd would start automatically. I could fix the former by doing `systemctl enable nfs-idmap`. However, I could not figure out how to make gssd start automatically. `/etc/systemd/system` has no mention of gssd, and `/lib/systemd/system/rpcgssd.service` gets installed, but is apparently unused (`systemctl enable rpcgssd` says `Failed to issue method call: No such file or directory`).

I can manually start gssd just fine (`rpc.gssd start`). How do I get it to start at reboot?

Comment: Where did you get the "apparently unused" from?

Comment: @grawity: see my edit. If I want to refer to this service, it doesn't find the file. I actually straced it, and the enable command only looks into /etc/systemd and /run/systemd, but not /lib/systemd.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error message on Fedora 20, and found this (currently) open Redhat bug: [RFE: allow systemctl enable work on symlinked units](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1014311)

Just like you, I could `service start rpcgssd`, but not `chkconfig rpcgssd on` or `systemctl enable rpcgssd`.  However, my `rpcgssd.service` file (in `/usr/lib/systemd/system`) was a symlink to `/usr/lib/systemd/nfs-secure.service`.

So, to fix, I ran `systemctl enable nfs-secure` instead, which bypassed the issue with symlinks listed in the above bug report.

Answer (score -1):

Add `SECURE_NFS="yes"` to `/etc/sysconfig/nfs`.

Comment: We’re looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context.  Don’t just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations.  Answers that don’t include explanations may be removed.